# Knockout js -> Bind to editable div text?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events

How can I bind an observable to an editable div text content?

Comment: You will need to write a custom binding for this, if "text" and "value" do not work.

Comment: Is the question not legit? Why the downvote?

Comment: At least it does not show much research effort. You can definitely improve the quality of your question by adding more information.

Comment: @Niko - Just because someone writes a short to the point question, does not mean he/she has not done research.

Comment: I actually upvoted your question, but it's always good to show an effort you've made...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You will need to modify the default "text" binding so that it is able to write the content of the edited div back to the observable. A simple custom binding handler for this task can look like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.editableText = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).on('blur', function() {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable( $(this).text() );
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).text(value);
    }
};
```

But please note that this example code requires jQuery.

Usage is as simple as this:

`<div contentEditable="true" data-bind="editableText: foo"></div>`

Here is an example (written in CoffeeScript): http://jsfiddle.net/aBUEu/1/

Comment: Way cool piece of work. Here's an updated fiddle where the link to knockout.js does not give a 404.  http://jsfiddle.net/aBUEu/18/

Comment: Only change I made was from text() to html().

Comment: I would use `$(element).on('keypress', function() {` in some cases.

Comment: @Alvaro have you tried with `keypress` or `keyup` or anything like that? I get some weir behaviour this way, the cursor is sent to the begining of the div when I press a key

Comment: @santiagoarizti I get that cursor behaviour too when I try using keyup, did you get anywhere with that?

Comment: @dove I removed the update part of the custom binding. In my case I only wanted to *read* from the div, but never *write* to it from the observable. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @dove I tried also to only execute the update function if the element was not focused, like this: `if (!$(element).is(":focus")) { /* updtate the element */ }`

Comment: @santiagoarizti thanks for the tips, I'm trying both and also updating on the focusin event as some updates are not happening after it is loaded, if that makes sense

Comment: If anyone else runs into the issue with the cursor jumping back to the start, in the update: add a check to make sure the element.text != value before setting it. That double tap was the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that by default, because changing text in editable div won't raise any event that would update the value in your model.

You will need a custom binding for this. You can read about it here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html