# HTML5 Contenteditable field and knockout: event rises before value binding

Tags: html, knockout.js, contenteditable

I'm trying to to display an editable field bound to an observable. I use knockout plus  'contenteditable' property (html5). After editing the field, its value should be posted to server as a json string.

The problem is with the value being posted to server. I expect to upload newly edited value, but instead of it I get old value.

Here is the illustration of the issue on jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/N8LDH/15/)

View:

```
<h2 contenteditable="true" data-bind="editableText: title, event: { change: valueChanged }"></h2>
```

editableText binder:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.editableText = { 
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).on('blur', function () {
             var observable = valueAccessor();
             observable($(this).text());
        });
     },
     update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
     var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
     $(element).text(value);
}};
```

'Change' Event Trigger:

```
 $('[contenteditable]').live('focus', function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.data('before', $this.html());
                return $this;
            }).live('blur paste', function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.data('before') !== $this.html()) {
                    $this.data('before', $this.html());
                    $this.trigger('change');
                }
                return $this;
            }).live('keypress', function(e) {
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 13) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.data('before') !== $this.html()) {
                        $this.data('before', $this.html());
                        $this.trigger('change');
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                return $this;
            });
```

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448367/knockout-js-bind-to-editable-div-text