# how to enable/disable button on editable div by knockout js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, frontend

```
 <div class="textarea textMsg" contenteditable="true" 
             data-bind="value: textMsg, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"></div>

        <button type="button" data-bind="click: save, enable: textMsg().length > 0  ">
            <span data-bind="visible: !sending()">Send</span>
            <span data-bind="visible: sending()">Sending</span>
        </button>
```

Why is enable: textMsg().length > 0 dose not detect if text is entered, if works on textarea, but dosen't work on editable div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in "value" binding does not work with div content, and neither does "text" or "textInput". You'll have to create a custom binding handler to get that to work. Try using the answer from this duplicate question [Knockout js -> Bind to editable div text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448367/knockout-js-bind-to-editable-div-text)